# how split string in java

Tags: java, android, date, calendar, alarmmanager

i have project in android, and i need split string, which is actually date here is the String that i'm going to split:

```
String datetime = "01/03/2013 09:00";
```

and this is how i call them:

```
int year = splitDateTime(dateTime)[0];
```

```
public int[] splitDateTime(String datetime){
        String date_time = datetime;
        String delimiter = "//:";

        String[] sParts;
        int[] intParts;

        sParts = date_time.split(delimiter);
        intParts = new int[sParts.length];

        for(int i =0; i < sParts.length ; i++)
            intParts[i] = Integer.parseInt(sParts[i]);

        return intParts;
    }
```

but it keeps giving me an error, so i would be happy if you help me out guys.
cheers

Comment: I'm parse the String into a Date using DateFormat and go from there.

Comment: There are better ways to get date,month, year and other elements from a date rather than splitting it. What if the dateformat changes ?

Comment: Your `deliminator` (please spell your code properly ;)) never appears in your string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I bet you mean something like:

```
String datetime = "01/03/2013 09:00";

String[] sParts = datetime.split("[/:\\s+]");
int[] iParts = new int[sParts.length];

for(int i = 0; i < sParts.length; i++)
    iParts[i] = Integer.parseInt(sParts[i]);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(iParts));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[1, 3, 2013, 9, 0]
```

Comment: i need it the out put to be this way 
1 3 2013 9 0

Comment: then all you need to do is change your 'delimiter' to "[/:\\s+]" and make sure you're passing the correct variable name to your function

Comment: to what should i convert it, cuz this new one u pass me is the same as the one above.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

```
String dateTime = "01/03/2013 09:00";
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
Date d = f.parse(dateTime);

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(d);
int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

Comment: i use it, but for some reason that i don't know when i get month it's give 2 not 3, and i don't know whats wrong with it.

Comment: usually android calender month starts from 0 for jan like that so you have to add one to get right value

Comment: java calendar month start with index 0 so always you need to add 1

Answer (score 0):

You may make use of regex, using something like `^(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+) (\d+):(\d)` and you can get each captured group.

Answer (score 0):

I think StringTokenizer based solution will be the fastest

```
public static int[] splitDateTime(String dateTime) {
    int[] intParts = new int[5];
    StringTokenizer t = new StringTokenizer(dateTime, "/ :");
    for (int i = 0; t.hasMoreTokens(); i++) {
        intParts[i] = Integer.parseInt(t.nextToken());
    }
    return intParts;
}

public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitDateTime("01/03/2013 09:00")));
}
```

output

```
[1, 3, 2013, 9, 0]
```